# Get upper triangular non-zero elements of a sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am trying to find an efficient way to retrieve a list / vector / array of the non-zero upper triangular elements of a sparse matrix in R.
For example:

```
    library(igraph)
    Gmini <- as.directed(graph.lattice(c(3,5)))
    GminiMat <- sparseMatrix(i=get.edgelist(Gmini)[,1],j=get.edgelist(Gmini)[,2],x=1:length(E(Gmini)))
    GminiMat

    15 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

    [1,]  .  1  .  2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [2,] 23  .  3  .  4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [3,]  . 25  .  .  .  5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [4,] 24  .  .  .  6  .  7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [5,]  . 26  . 28  .  8  .  9  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [6,]  .  . 27  . 30  .  .  . 10  .  .  .  .  .  .
    [7,]  .  .  . 29  .  .  . 11  . 12  .  .  .  .  .
    [8,]  .  .  .  . 31  . 33  . 13  . 14  .  .  .  .
    [9,]  .  .  .  .  . 32  . 35  .  .  . 15  .  .  .
    [10,]  .  .  .  .  .  . 34  .  .  . 16  . 17  .  .
    [11,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 36  . 38  . 18  . 19  .
    [12,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 37  . 40  .  .  . 20
    [13,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 39  .  .  . 21  .
    [14,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 41  . 43  . 22
    [15,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 42  . 44  .
```

So ideally i would like to make a function getUpper(mat) such that
    getUpper(GminiMat)
would yield the vector of 1:22 (the upper triangular non-zero entries of GminiMat)

Ideally, I need a fairly memory and speed efficient approach since I may need to apply it to large systems (e.g. the matrix could come from a multi-dimensional lattice with a several hundred nodes in each dimension).

Comment: `?upper.tri` is what you're looking for

Comment: This gives back a mask of trues and falses, but it looks like it will take a bit more to actually extract the entries themselves. The bigger problem is that the matrix is no longer sparse, so it won't be feasible in places where I need to use a sparse matrix (e.g. for very large system dimensions).

Comment: You would have to do `x[upper.tri(x)]`. But it is a bad idea because `upper.tri(x)` is a full (non-parse) matrix so it defeats the purpose of using sparse matrices in the first place. It will be slow and could easily make you run out of memory if you are using large matrices. Working on `summary` (or an equivalent sparse representation) is the way to go.

Comment: Well you do need to munge it a bit more GminiMat[upper.tri(GminiMat)] will give you the values. It won't preserve the structure! What do you want just the values? or the structure with other values converted to NAs?

Comment: In this case, I just need the values. These are acting as edge indices with the upper and lower triangular portions of the matrix corresponding to directed edges pointing in opposite directions. I am trying to get ahold of edges going in one direction so I can sample them and then find the corresponding edges going in the opposite direction. It is also useful so that if I need to look up an edge going in one direction, I can find its counterpart quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method `triu` in package Matrix that will return the upper triangle while preserving sparseness:

```
triu(GminiMat)
15 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"

 [1,] . 1 . 2 . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [2,] . . 3 . 4 . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [3,] . . . . . 5 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [4,] . . . . 6 . 7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [5,] . . . . . 8 .  9  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [6,] . . . . . . .  . 10  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [7,] . . . . . . . 11  . 12  .  .  .  .  .
 [8,] . . . . . . .  . 13  . 14  .  .  .  .
 [9,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  . 15  .  .  .
[10,] . . . . . . .  .  .  . 16  . 17  .  .
[11,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  . 18  . 19  .
[12,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 20
[13,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  . 21  .
[14,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 22
[15,] . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `summary` function. See

```
subset(summary(GminiMat), j > i)
```

and take it from there. Maybe:

```
getUpper <- function(mat) subset(summary(mat), j > i)$x
```